# How to use mapping in React JS for Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so I'm trying to make some web page about hotel room information using React JS and I wanted to change the name, description, image of the page depending on the room type the user choose. But I don't know how to map the image, can somebody help me to do the mapping ?
I haven't make the button tag to change the room type yet.

Here's my room.js code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Row, Col, Container} from "react-bootstrap"

const RoomInfo = [
  {
    MainPhoto:"",
    RoomType:"Superior Twin",
    RoomDescription:"",
    LittlePhoto:'Photo1.jpg'
  },
  {
    MainPhoto:"",
    RoomType:"Double Room Twin",
    RoomDescription:"",
    LittlePhoto:'Photo1.jpg'
  },
]
const Room = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Container fluid={true} className="p-0">
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <h1 className="text-center"> Check out our room</h1>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </>
    )
}

export default Room
```

Comment: Could you add extra info like what you expect and what you try?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly.
you can do `<img src={variable} />` and than assign the variable the link to the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can using map array like this to render element from an array:

```
...
<h1 className="text-center"> Check out our room</h1>
{
  RoomInfo.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <img src={item.LittlePhoto} />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
...
```

Comment: hi thanks for the feedback, but is it correct if write the image source by LittlePhoto:"Photo1.jpg" or there should be another way to define the jpg file in array ?

Comment: LittlePhoto should be store image links or path to image. You can not store only name of image